# How to enable stereoscopic 3D in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: windows-7, deus-ex-human-revolution, stereo-3d

I can't enable stereoscopic 3D in Deus Ex: Human Revolution (the button appears red)? I have the latest drivers and am using Windows 7 x64 but the game does not allow me to enable this feature.

I'm using an i7 with 8GB of RAM and an ATI Radeon HD 5670 graphics card.

What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

I Couldnt get it to work by stock either, but the solution given in [this forum post](http://widescreengamingforum.com/forum/forums/stereoscopic-3d-gaming/general-stereoscopic-3d-discussions/16660/workaround-enabling-3d) worked.

**But, be very careful. This involves registry editing, which can be very dangerous if you get it wrong.**

Click on Start button, type `regedit`, then click OK. Navigate to the following place in the registry (Windows 7, 64BIT. Should work in most OS's) ...

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21...\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HR\Graphics]
```

and edit `StereoMode`, setting the value to `4`.

You may have to repeat occasionally these steps, the game may reset the value back to 0 if you change any of the gfx settings.

Comment: Just posting an "answer" that is just a link isn't particularly helpful. You answer should contain enough detail to stand on it's own, otherwise what happens if the link goes down?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the actual answer.

Comment: Much better :) I've tweaked it a bit so the registry stuff is highlighted and I'm swapping my -1 for a +1.

Comment: Thanks for try, but I was not successfull. I set the value in registry to 4 but ingame option remains red, unable to change it. Any other idea how to run this up?