# Is it possible to play Deus Ex: HR in stereo 3D on Windows 10?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, windows-10, stereo-3d, steam-vr

I'm trying to find a way to make the Steam version of Deus Ex: Human Revolution (not the [Director's Cut](https://store.steampowered.com/app/238010/Deus_Ex_Human_Revolution__Directors_Cut/), I have the regular version, but can't obtain the url since it's been removed from the store) to let me enable Stereo 3D but not having any luck so far. I remember being able to turn it on briefly many years ago on a Windows 7 machine with GeForce 9800GT, it was real slow, but it worked. Now that I have a modern Windows 10 PC with a 2080 Super and Valve Index VR headset I wanted to try and to start it in Steam's Big Screen mode in side-by-side stereo 3D mode.

So far I've only found [very old](https://www.mtbs3d.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=14700) forum threads dating back to 2012-2014 mentioning older non-steam versions and special patches which are of no use today, and certain [obsolete](https://www.wsgf.org/dr/deus-ex-human-revolution/en) NVidia 3D Vision settings and [Windows 7/8 -specific graphics settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/stereoscopic-3d) which are not found in Windows 10. [This old answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/how-to-enable-stereoscopic-3d-in-deus-ex-human-revolution) doesn't help also.

Is it possible at all to launch DX:HR in stereo 3D on a modern Windows 10 system? If so, what would be the steps to make it playable with a VR headset?

Comment: Which version of the game do you have, the normal release, or the Director's Cut? An old question I asked on Arqade had a comment about how the Director's Cut was significantly more buggy than the original release.

Comment: Not the director's cut, the normal version, I'll edit this into the question.